# How to retrive the whole object at once from Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just started using Firebase for my Swift programming . I managed to fetch some data from the Json using the following :

```
   let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("Posts").child("1").child("Post").child("Like").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (Snapshot) in
            let Value = Snapshot.value as? Int
            print(Value!)
        })
```

However , I am trying to fetch the whole object first and then get the value of each element later .  So here is my attempt but my app keeps getting terminated :

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("Posts").child("1").child("Post").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot.children.value(forKey: "Like") as? Int)
                print(snapshot.children.value(forKey: "Image") as? String)
        })
```

Any idea where am I making a mistake ? 
here is my Json :

```
{
    "Posts": {
        "1": {
            "Post": {
                "Poster_ID": "ID",
                "Post_Time_stamp": "12:12:12AM",
                "Image": "img.png",
                "Video": "video.mov",
                "Like": "3",
                "Dislike": "0",
                "Massage": {
                    "Massage_ID": "MSG_ID",
                    "Massager": "id",
                    "Massage_Time_stamp": "12:12:12PM",
                    "Massage_content": "comment"
                }


            }
        },
        "2": {
            "Post": {
                "Poster_ID": "ID",
                "Post_Time_stamp": "12:12:12AM",
                "Image": "img.png",
                "Video": "video.mov",
                "Like": "3",
                "Dislike": "0",
                "Massage": {
                    "Massage_ID": "MSG_ID",
                    "Massager": "id",
                    "Massage_Time_stamp": "12:12:12PM",
                    "Massage_content": "comment"
                }


            }
        }
    },
    "User": {
        "1": {
            "User_name": "name",
            "User_pass": "pass",
            "User_avatar": "img.png"
        },
        "2": {
            "User_name": "name",
            "User_pass": "pass",
            "User_avatar": "img.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your firebase db

Comment: @NiravD I've updated the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get the post object you need to access `snapshot.value` also observe for `value` event instead of `childAdded`.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.child("Posts").child("1").child("Post")
   .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

   if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
       print(dict["Like"] as? Int ?? 0)
   }       
})
```

Comment: Thanks , this answer works . But I am not yet convinced why the answer given by  @Dravidian is not working .  Any idea ?

Comment: @DanialKosarifa Welcome mate:) Below answer not work because in that it is accessing children of its and that will give you array if you are having db inside your post postid1: postdetail, postid2: postdetail and so on but you simply having post with value

Answer (score 2):

Try printing `snapshot` first and see if you are able to retrieve anything if no, Try this

Use FIRDataEventType as `.value` instead of `.childAdded`. Since `.childAdded` is only fired when a child node is added to that reference node, `.value` retrieves the current value as that reference point..

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("Posts").child("1").child("Post").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            print(snapshot.children.value(forKey: "Like") as? Int)
            print(snapshot.children.value(forKey: "Image") as? String)
    })
```

Comment: Unclear what the difference is here without some additional explanation.

Comment: FIRDataEventType; OP is using `.childAdded`, i am suggesting `.value`

Comment: Apologies, Didn't see that optional... Yes its gonna print nil.. Thanks for pointing out..

Comment: Thanks for your answer , once I print the snapshot I get the object but when I print `(snapshot.children.value(forKey: "Like") as? Int` or ` print(snapshot.children.value(forKey: "Image") as? String` the app get terminated . The console says "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Like.'" Any idea why ? because the syntax makes sense XD